# How to calculate Cronbach's alpha

Tags: agreement-statistics, cronbachs-alpha, reproducible-research

For my dissertation I am observing horse race videos to see if horses are right or left handed. In flat races where the horse comes out of the starting stalls I observe which leg (right or left) they first use as they emerge. My tutor suggested that I have another person re-score 5% of my observations and use Cronbach's Alpha as a test of 'reproducibility' for my observations. I have no idea how to use the test, so would anyone be able to help with this please? If you should know of an on-line tool to do this that would be great too.

Answer (score -1):

Here, the Cronbach Alpha would be a measure of whether the observations are reproducible in the sense that your observations are consistent with the other person's. It is a normalized coefficient, larger values indicate better reliability of observations.  See for example https://www.statsoft.com/Textbook/Reliability-and-Item-Analysis for more details. The Statistica software allows you to easily compute Cronbach Alpha, if you don't have a regular access at your uni, you can download a trial version from the mentioned website.